# Changes background color to black few times in RowSupportFragment in FireTV on item selection

Tags: android, android-tv, leanback, amazon-fire-tv

I am using RowsSupportFragment of lean-back library for my TV application.
It changes background color of the fragment to black while selecting items (few times color changes to black where as we have set background color transparent) in FireTV only, whereas same code is working fine in AndroidTV

How i solve this issue please suggest.

[image]

Comment: Could you provide the logs?

Comment: i didn't get anything in log regarding this issue

Comment: @abielita I have shared my code please go through this. [code link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1lBIi-w7VcJ9X6Ef77_EdIeA-_4HkkusN)

Comment: @Manoj Patidar Have you got any solution regarding black screen issue for leanback library